# Заполнение таблицы в MS SQL через python

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, sql-server

Создал программу, которая должна заполнить таблицу случайными значениями (для тестов). Вручную заполненная таблица и типы данных есть на прикрепленном изображении.
Вот код:

```
import random
import pypyodbc

mySQLServer = "DESKTOP-1FN3B94\SQLEXPRESS"
myDatabase = "Coachs"

try:
    connection = pypyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                                  "Server=" + mySQLServer + ";"
                                  "Database=" + myDatabase + ";")
except:
    print("Ошибка подключения к базе данных")
cursor = connection.cursor()
names = ['Абакум', 'Абрам', 'Абросим'...]
sure_names = ['Абабков', 'Абакумов', 'Абалышев',...]
exams = ['ОГЭ,', 'ЕГЭ,', 'ОГЭ,ЕГЭ,']
subs = ['математика', 'русский язык',...]
areas = ['дзержинский', 'индустриальный', 'кировский',...]
streets = ['Ленина', ' Вагонная', 'Пушкина',...]
for i in range(3):
    age = random.randrange(20, 70)
    like = random.randrange(25, 100)
    dislike = random.randrange(2, 10)
    number = random.randrange(89012303027, 89090000000)
    price = random.randrange(400, 851)
    name = random.choice(names) + " " + random.choice(sure_names)
    area = random.choice(areas) + ",все"
    sub = random.choice(subs)
    exam = random.choice(exams)
    address_num = random.randrange(5, 105)
    address = random.choice(streets) + ", " + str(address_num)
    mySQLQuery = ("INSERT INTO dbo.Tutor_Info VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
    ?, ?, ?, ?)",(name, i + 6, str(number), age, area, exam, sub, like, 
    dislike, price, address))
    cursor.execute(mySQLQuery)
connection.close()
```

А ошибку он выдает такую:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Владелец/.PyCharmCE2019.2/config/scratches/База данных/ТЕст.py", line 41, in <module>
    cursor.execute(mySQLQuery)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1626, in execute
    self.execdirect(query_string)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1650, in execdirect
    c_query_string = ctypes.c_char_p(query_string)
TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of tuple instance

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cursor.execute()` ожидает строку с SQL запросом в качестве первого аргумента. Вы передали ей кортеж (`tuple`).

Попробуйте так:

```
mySQLQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.Tutor_Info VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
parms = (name, i + 6, str(number), age, area, exam, sub, like,  dislike, price, address)
cursor.execute(mySQLQuery, parms)
```

---

не забудьте сделать `commit` в конце:

```
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно перестало вызывать ошибку, но когда я захотел посмотреть результат в SSMS, там ничего не добавилось (так и осталось 6 строк)

Comment: @S1riyS, commit не забыли сделать?

Comment: забыл, а куда и что именно нужно дописать?

Comment: Слава MaxU! (спасибо, помогло)